# Email div text content using PHP mail function

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to be able to email content that is in my webpage using the php mail function. However, I'm running into some issues. I am following this [Email Div Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257801/email-div-content) question that has already been posted as a guide but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Here is part of my HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="">
<input name="my_hidden_field" id="my_hidden_field" type="hidden" value=""></input>
<div name="priceestimates" id="priceestimates">
<p>The contents of this webpage are not permanent and can change.</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my jquery where I'm trying to input the text from the div into the hidden input:

```
$("#correctinfo").click(function() {
    $("#my_hidden_field").val($("#priceestimates").text());
});
```

Here is my PHP where I'm getting the value of the input and sending it in the boxy (I left out most of the PHP mail function because I didn't want to flood my question with code):

```
$my_hidden_field = $_POST['my_hidden_field'];

$body = $my_hidden_field;
```

Comment: try to read about jquery, id attribute in html and how a form submit works

Comment: That was helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following jquery script using form submit event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function() { //notice submit event
        $("#my_hidden_field").val($("#priceestimates").html()); //notice html function instead of text();
    });
});
</script>
```